# How can I replace bits or string with React component, react-router-dom Link or an anchor tag <a></a>

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

How can I replace bits of string with links or components

This is a sample of the data

```
Ownership of Product/DiJUHl5zCE changed from Org/abcd to Org/efghi
Stage changed to completed for Payment of 254.15 gbp on Cycle Cycle/svgAjnox5t
Ownership of Product/DSGDHFHFDH changed from Org/sdef to Org/juhtr
Stage changed to completed for Payment of 4.15 gbp on Cycle Cycle/fdlkgdfkjdfl
```

I want to replace

Ownership of Product/DiJUHl5zCE changed from Org/dvju to Org/kijuy

Ownership of [Product](/product/Product/DiJUHl5zCE) changed from [OrgName](/org/Org/abcd) to [OrgName](/org/Org/efghi)

```
Ownership of <a href="/product/Product/DiJUHl5zCE">Product</a> changed from <a href="/org/Org/abcd">OrgName</a> to <a href="/org/Org/efghi">OrgName</a>
```

and

Stage changed to completed for Payment of 254.15 gbp on Cycle Cycle/svgAjnox5t

Stage changed to completed for Payment of 254.15 gbp on Cycle [Cycle](/cycle/Cycle/svgAjnox5t)

```
Stage changed to completed for Payment of 254.15 gbp on Cycle <a href="/cycle/Cycle/svgAjnox5t">Cycle</a>
```

I also have a regex

```
/([\w\d]+)\/([\w\d-]+)/g;
```

https://regex101.com/r/VrqlI7/1

that returns the groups but if I use replace() or replaceAll() the second argument returns string and in the browser it comes out as [object, object]

basically pass each line through a function and return a div with bits of text replaced with links

I am relatively new to react. any help much appriciated.

If I use `` at the start
[image]
[image]

if I use `` withing the href
[image]
[image]

How can I get this to display as links, Please advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replaceAll` with a callback

```
s.replaceAll(/([\w\d]+)\/([\w\d-]+)/g, (a) => {
  if (a.startsWith("Product")) { return `<a href="/product/${a}">${a}</a>` }
  else if (a.startsWith("Org")) { return `<a href="/org/${a}">${a}</a>` }
  else { return a }
})
```

Edit:
If you want to render links as react components, you can split the text by pattern using `split()` and then `map()` over the resulting array to replace the parts you need, like this:

```
const lPrefixMap = { 'Product': '/product/', 'Cycle': '/cycle/', 'Org': '/org/' };
const renderedContent = text.split(/([\w\d]+\/[\w\d-]+)/g).map((v, idx) => {
  if (idx & 1) {
    const linkType = v.split('/')[0];
    const prefix = lPrefixMap[linkType];
    return (<Link to={`${prefix}${v}`}>{v}</Link>);
  }
  return <span>v</span>;
});
// You can then render this in your JSX code like this:
return <div>{renderedContent}</div>
```

Comment: What am I doing wrong? 
    checkNotifications = (item) => {
        if (!item) return;
        const { message } = item;
        let text;

        text = message.text.replaceAll(/([\w\d]+)\/([\w\d-]+)/g, (a) => {
            if (a.startsWith("Product")) { return `<a href="/product/${a}">${a}</a>` }
            else if (a.startsWith("Org")) { return `<a href="/org/${a}">${a}</a>` }
            else { return a }
        })
        
        return <div>{text}</div>;
    };

Comment: The output Ownership of <a href="/product/Product/Vbffh8eBa7">Product/Vbffh8eBa7</a> changed from <a href="/org/Org/loopcycle">Org/loopcycle</a> to <a href="/org/Org/default">Org/default</a>

Comment: The output comes out as text on the browser and not as jsx. Any advice?

Comment: @Zinox You can use this property to interpret your text as html `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: text }}`

Comment: Thank you @dmitryguzeev this works to a certian extent. Is there a way I can use another componeent? or a <Link /> tag from reacte-router-dom